# mysql count table like in database

Tags: mysql

I have table with different name like `dev1User Dev2user`

I would like to count total table name start with `dev1`

This will count number of tables:

```
USE databasename; SHOW TABLES; SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

Comment: Query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, you can access that like any other table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*)
 FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabasename' AND
       table_name like 'dev1%'
```

Comment: or, `WHERE table_schema = 'mydatabasename' AND table_name LIKE 'dev1%'`

Comment: @spencer7593 i updated